# Cant purge nvidia-331-updates

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, dpkg

Just cant install/purge/update ANYTHING because `apt-get` tells me it MUST DELETE `nvidia-331-updates` before that. Purging/installing/deleting `nvidia-331-updates` fails with a message from `dpkg`.

```
Removing nvidia-331-updates (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4) ...
stop: Unknown instance: 
userdel: existing lock file /etc/subuid.lock without a PID
userdel: cannot lock /etc/subuid; try again later.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-331-updates (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 16
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-331-updates
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/subuid.lock` and try again.

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo lsof /etc/subuid.lock` ?

Comment: That you guys. Just removed /etc/subuid.lock and /etc/subgid.lock and its fine now

Answer (score 1):

Answer from OPs comment:

> That you guys. Just removed `/etc/subuid.lock` and
>   `/etc/subgid.lock` and its fine now

Answer (score -3):

You could maybe try this instead, and it might work fine, and enter this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-311-updates
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: How come this can solve the issue with the lockfile?